# Creating a pie chart (Google) from an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I want to create a pie chart using a set of data from an array of a data type that returns a String and a double but when I put this values in the drwchart function it gives me nothing, 
this is my last tried

```
function drawChart1() {

    // Create the data table.

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');


    data.addRows(largo);


    // Add empty rows

    for  (var i= 0;i = largo;i++){
        data.setCell(i, 0, est[i].getNombre() );
        data.setCell(i, 1, est[i].getmonto());
    }


    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'Ganancias por Juego',
                   'width':700,
                   'height':400};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

GetNombre() returns a String and getmonto() returns a double 
I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The pie chart works until I use these functions but the get functions works OK.

Comment: What is your `for` loop doing? You probably want something like: `for (var i = 0; i < largo.length; i++)` but I'm not even sure what `largo` is...and why you're using `est[i]` inside...

Comment: Are `getNombre` and `getmonto` methods of whatever class `est[i]` is?  Maybe you meant to do `getNombre(est[i])` ?

Comment: largo is est.lenght and getNombre and getmonto are methos because est is an array of a datatype